# Do I add the appropriate ability score modifier to all skills or only the ones I'm proficient in?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills

I'm having trouble fully understanding how skills work. I think I have it mostly understood but I'm curious if I would be able to add my stat modifiers to all skills even if it was a skill my character probably wouldn't use such as performance. Being a warlock I wouldn't use performance even but it would be odd being good at performance even though I would never do it.

Comment: Why is it odd that a character with high Charisma is good at Performance?

Comment: @anaximander I think what he means is that his warlock wouldn't be putting on any sort of performance (based on how he plays the character, the PC isn't one for doing that), he could just be a good talker, but the stats say that he should be good at performing because his CHA is high.

Comment: @bubbajake00 That's kind of my point. The character might not be inclined to give a performance, but, given that they're very "charismatic", then by the game's definition of what charisma is, they *would* be good at it if they tried. While it might seem odd to picture this particular character performing, that's separate. The idea of a high-charisma character being good at a thing that requires charisma - even though they never specifically trained for it - doesn't seem all that odd to me.

Comment: @anaximander I've known people that are great at performing theater, but couldn't speak publicly at all, and vice versa.  Or people that are very persuasive (persuasion), but couldn't successfully tell a lie to save their life (deception).  And yeah, the basic game definition you mentioned I agree with, just from a character customization standpoint, it doesn't seem as good.

Comment: @bubbajake00 Which is precisely why I said "by the *game's* definition of what charisma is". You're right, there's a big difference between performing, persuading, lying, etc. but in game terms, that's just how it goes. I guess the discrepancy is covered by what you take proficiency in.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### There are no Skill Checks, only Ability Checks.

In other words, you don't use the **skills** for the things you do, you use the **ability** (Charisma, in your case), and add proficiency if the DM decides a proficiency would help, and that you are proficient in it. As back up for this assertion, notice that in all checks, you always add(or subtract) your Ability Modifiers even though there are times where a skill does not apply (like Constitution checks), *but* in no case does a check let you add *only* the skill you are proficient in, and not the ability.

Adding the Performance skill proficiency does not always mean you are performing. As an example, in Hoard of the Dragon Queen, there is a scene where proficiency in Performance can aid your character see through a ruse.

Answer (score 14):

In 5E, skill checks *are* ability checks. From the [basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#Skills):

> Each ability covers a broad range of capabilities, including skills that a character or a monster can be proficient in. A skill represents a specific aspect of an ability score, and an individual's proficiency in a skill demonstrates a focus on that aspect. 
>   [...]
>   For example, a Dexterity check might reflect a character's attempt to pull off an acrobatic stunt, to palm an object, or to stay hidden. Each of these aspects of Dexterity has an associated skill: Acrobatics, Sleight of Hand, and Stealth, respectively. So a character who has proficiency in the Stealth skill is particularly good at Dexterity checks related to sneaking and hiding.

You will see these checks written as, for example, "Dexterity (Stealth)"  or "Strength (Athletics)".

So, naturally, you add your ability modifier to these checks. If you're trained otherwise especially good at a particular thing — like Stealth — that's where you add the proficiency bonus. So, in summary:

- **Ability modifier:** Every ability check
- **Proficiency bonus:** Added in addition to that when you are proficient in that skill.

You say:

> Being a warlock I wouldn't use performance even but it would be odd being good at performance even though I would never do it.

There are *lots* of things you might have natural instinct in but no inclination to do. A paladin might be very, very good at lying, but might never do it. Someone who is very strong might be very good at bashing down doors, but... maybe they're really polite and always knock.

Basically, your ability scores represent your natural talent (or... "ability"), while skill proficiency represents specific focus — either through training, extra interest, or simply *additional* natural ability in a certain area.

Charisma (Intimidate) seems *very* thematically appropriate for the Warlock class as presented, but if *your* warlock would never do such a thing, that's fine. If you've chosen to be proficient in that skill and still never use it, well, okay, but even if you haven't decided to focus on it, you do have a natural edge due to high charisma.

(As a sort of aside: all of the traditional ability scores get a *little* weird if you look at them too hard. It's best, like so many things in D&D, to just accept that that's how the game model works and not overthink it.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you add your stat modifiers to all skills, and anyone can try almost any skill.  You add your proficiency modifier also, to those skill in which you are proficient (usually 2 to 4 from your class, 2 from your background, maybe 1 or 2 from your race).